# How make kalibrate-rtl and rtlsdr-scanner work with my modem?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, gsm

The modem is a d-link hsupa 3.75g dwm-156 .
Documentation is here:
[Documentation](http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DWM/DWM%20156/Manual/DWM%20156_Manual_EN_UK.pdf)

When I try:

> root@kali:~# kal -s GSM900 -v
>   No supported devices found.

In this page there some AT commands may be useful
[AT Commands](http://radekp.github.io/qtmoko/api/atcommands.html)

In the documentation says it supports GSM850-900 bands and greater.

My system:
Linux kali 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux